# Preencher SELECT através de formulário (PHP)

Tags: php, mysql

Tenho o seguinte código:

```
<?php
include("conexao.php");

$sql = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM escola e
WHERE coordenador IN (SELECT ec.coordenador 
               FROM escola_coordenador ec 
              WHERE ec.coordenador = '1')
AND uf = 'PR' AND situacao = 'contratado'");
$row = mysql_fetch_array($sql); 
$total = $row['COUNT(*)'];
echo $total;

?>
```

Ele mostra a quantidade de registro no banco.

Eu preciso de um formulário para que o usuário digite: o número do coordenador e a UF e então aparece a quantidade em $total.

Alguém consegue me ajudar?

Comment: O que você sabe de HTML e HTTP?

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss, quase nada :-/

Comment: Então acho melhor começar estudando desde o início e tentar fazer por si só primeiro, para identificar melhor suas dificuldades.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consegui resolver meu problema.

Criei um arquivo index.html:

```
<form action="script.php" method="post">
Coordenador <input type=text name=coordenador><br>
Estado (UF): <input type=text name=uf><br>
<input type=submit value="Buscar">
</form>
```

E um arquivo script.php:

```
<?php
include("conexao.php");

$coordenador = $_POST["coordenador"];
$uf = $_POST["uf"]

$sql = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM escola e
WHERE coordenador IN (SELECT ec.coordenador 
               FROM escola_coordenador ec 
              WHERE ec.coordenador = '$coordenador')
AND uf = '$uf' AND situacao = 'contratado'");
$row = mysql_fetch_array($sql); 
$total = $row['COUNT(*)'];
echo $total;

?>
```